# Storing data in NumPy array while loop

Tags: python, numpy

Storing data in NumPy array while loop

I want to store 3 variables (time, speed, position) into a NumPy array. The storing process should add a new value each time the loop is complete. The loop accounts for the time and the speed and positions are functions of this time. I could do it using a list however, according to what I've seen on the tutorial Numpy arrays are more efficient for large data which is my case. My question is how can I do that using an array. I was thinking maybe using append could do the job, but the problem is that append creates a new NumPy array instead of simply adding values. Also as far as I know NumPy is not mutable in size. Therefore every time I add another axis other arrays will be created which may not be efficient. Any suggestions on this matter?

```
duration = 3600
time = 0
data= np.array([s(t)], [x(t)], [t])
while time <= duration:
   function_speed = s(t)
   function_position = x(t)
   data = add values (s, x, t)
   time +=1
```

I was thinking maybe creating a large array then replace each value accordingly. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Stick with the list append, or assign values in a preallocated array.  The timings are about the same.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that your program will run for a specific `duration`, you can preallocate the space necessary, using [np.empty](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html):

```
duration = 3600
time = 0
data = np.empty(shape=(duration+2, 3))  # duration + time at 0 + final iteration
data[0] = s(t), x(t), t
while time <= duration:
    ...
    data[time+1] = s(t), x(t), t
    time += 1
```